# getAttribute return value null (between Servlet and jsp in javaEE)

Tags: jakarta-ee

I tried to learn Java EE and here is a very simple example :

In my servlet :

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Servlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String message1 = "Alo alo";
    int mess2 = 3;
    request.setAttribute("test", mess2);
    request.setAttribute("aloMessage", message1);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

And in my jsp file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <%
  String getMessage = (String)request.getAttribute("aloMessage");
  out.println( getMessage+" abc" );
  %>
  <br>
  <%
  Integer k = (Integer)request.getAttribute("test");
  out.println( k+" abc" );
  %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is a result : 
    null abc
    null abc

I don't know why getAttribute return value null ?

Comment: Please, put your complete example. Thanks

Comment: I edited my post and add my complete code. Thank you

Comment: See this example: https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your jsp page is losing request session.

There is alternate way to do it.

you can set in servlet like

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("test", mess2);
request.getSession().setAttribute("aloMessage", message1);
```

and in jsp get it like

```
String getMessage = (String)session.getAttribute("aloMessage");
```

out.println( getMessage+" abc" );